# Google Analytics Age As Secondary Dimension Reduces Results

Tags: google-analytics, reporting

I am trying to distribute Pageviews by URL v/s Age as secondary URL, but the result reduces and shows only a set of old URL's but not the new ones.

Here is a report for last 3 years without secondary dimension. This shows 1009 URL's

[image]

When added a Secondary Dimension "Age" the results come down to 9 for same period.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that age is only applied in certain scenarios where an ad campaign has targeted certain demographics.

What you are likely seeing is the subset of your data that only contains that dimension.

When selecting a dimension, there isn't an "everything else" label unless it is explicitly set, so you won't see the rest of you data - you can assume that "all data minus the age data equals the rest of the data". This is the same scenario as when you set a custom dimension - if you only record the dimension when there is a value (e.g. a promocode on an ecommerce transaction), you will only ever see traffic that has a value applied.

In this instance there would need to have been "no age set" on the dimension, to get the rest of the traffic - which is how demographics work (again slightly unsure). This is like "direct/none" has a default that is put on source medium when there is no source or medium to be discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Thresholds are applied to prevent anyone viewing a report from inferring the demographics or interests of individual users. When a report contains Age, Gender, or Interest Category (as a primary or secondary dimension, or as part of an applied segment), a threshold may be applied and some data may be withheld from the report.

Documentation: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2799357?hl=en

My article with test: https://www.analyticstraps.com/i-report-con-i-dati-demografici-non-tornano/